# Rollback not working mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.41, for Linux (x86_64)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Rollback not working on mysql.

I tried all the suggestions on stackoverflow.

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
UPDATE bankaccounts SET funds=funds-100 WHERE accountno='ACC1';
UPDATE bankaccounts SET funds=funds+100 WHERE accountno='ACC2';
ROLLBACK;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1
```

not working

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE bankaccounts SET funds=funds-100 WHERE accountno='ACC1';
UPDATE bankaccounts SET funds=funds+100 WHERE accountno='ACC2';
ROLLBACK;
```

not working

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do your table use a transactional engine, example InnoDB?. I can't reproduce the problem with a transactional engine (InnoDB), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iQf40D5d).